# For an active power factor correction circuit (PFC boost,) is there any characterisation graph between input voltage and power factor?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, mains, power-factor-correction

Just like the regulation graph (ouput voltage vs. input voltage) for a voltage regulator, is there a similar graph (power factor vs. input voltage) for a power factor corrector circuit?

My aim is to understand under what input voltage conditions the power factor would be the worst regulated. I couldn't find this info in any standard PFC controller datasheets.

A similar graph is found in  this *[paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323665423_Adaptive_and_Nonlinear_Control_Techniques_Applied_to_SEPIC_Converter_in_DC-DC_PFC_CCM_and_DCM_Modes_Using_HIL_Simulation/download?_tp=eyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZpcnN0UGFnZSI6Il9kaXJlY3QiLCJwYWdlIjoiX2RpcmVjdCJ9fQ)* - though I'm not sure about the authenticity  of this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(Note: these are several questions, and I'm not sure if it's a language barrier or what, but I will answer them as given, without trying to surmise a meaning or phrasing I don't understand.)

**Re: title, 1st paragraph:** You can measure and plot whatever you want; it's not clear what you want answered here.  It could be plotted at just a few points (say 90, 120, 240 VAC), or many.  A paper, showing off a particular design, might do more points (as linked).  A finished power supply might do it, but perhaps only for the important voltages (such as the above list).

**Re: 2nd paragraph:** PF depends on all the components in the system; it wouldn't be very meaningful for a controller datasheet (the controller, without all those particular components and values) to give such data.  An application note discussing an evaluation module (a particular embodiment of some controller in question), perhaps.

Other than these mere circumstantial points, it is impossible for us to say for sure why datasheets don't give these.  The correct venue to address such a concern is to the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

While the graph axes are different to those in the example in the question, in  [TI Designs 1-kW, Compact, 97.5% Efficiency, Digital PFC for AC/DC PSUs With eMeter Reference Design](https://www.tij.co.jp/lit/ug/tidubk8b/tidubk8b.pdf?ts=1707020828434) there are the following Performance Curves, where Figure 9 shows a variation of Power Factor over some different Input Voltages:

[image]

Suspect that different manufacturers don't perform test measurements in the same way. This doesn't attempt to answer all the posted questions, but just serves as an example of some measurements made for one one design.